# $firebaseArray join with other table

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a Firebase table named Orders:

```
{productID: xyz, 
 userID: abc, 
 quantity: 100}
```

There is another table Products containing product details. When showing a user's orders, I need to show some product details along with each order. How can I use `$firebaseArray` for this purpose?

`$firebaseArray` seems can only go with a table. Here, I'd need to query each ordered product's detail and add the detail to each order.  Is the `$extend` the way to go?  If so, any good example would be very appreciated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/f78d4a224c06a643ddfa

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/uoe5yt8x/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721460/firebase-data-normalized-how-should-i-fetch-a-collection-based-on-this-structur/21733457#21733457

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query for multiple records in firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709227/query-for-multiple-records-in-firebase)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512039/using-firebase-util-to-resolve-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: Hi @Kato, thanks for your comments. Following them, I've found the first example here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/blob/master/src/NormalizedCollection/README.md to be very similar to my problem and I am able to do what I need now. Firebase.util is very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this one.  What you want to use is the [NormalizedCollection](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/blob/master/src/NormalizedCollection/README.md).  This way you can write your statement something like this:

```
var fb = new Firebase('https://<instance>.firebaseio.com');
var norm = new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
   fb.child('products'),
   fb.child('productDetails')
);
var productsRef = $firebaseArray(norm.ref());
```